# count occurrences of species per site in matrix in R

Tags: matrix

I have the species by site matrix like the one below. Where species are in columns (a,b,c,d) and sites are in rows (W,X,Y,Z). I would like to know the number of occurrences of species per site without considering their abundances. In other words species "a" will occurred 4 times, species b and d occurred twice, and species c occurs once. If I used either colSums or rowSums it counts the abundances which is not what I want. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
x <- matrix(c(1,4,1,1,0,6,1,0,0,20,0,0,1,1,0,0), nrow = 4, 
            dimnames = list(c("W","X","Y","Z"), c("a","b","c","d")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the answer offered by a friend, to get the occurrences per species you need to use: `colSums(x>0)`

This assuming that 0 means absence.